# Command line reverb parameters for FluidSynth

Tags: command-line-arguments, fluidsynth

The command below renders an audio file using FluidSynth:

```
fluidsynth -a jack  -o synth.gain=.8  \
   -C0 -R1 -T wav  -F test.wav mypiano.sf2 test.midi
```

The `-R1` parameter activates the reverb. So far so good.

I wonder how I can set the reverb level, reverb width, roomsize and damping.

I tried adding parameters which I respectively found at  http://www.fluidsynth.org/api/fluidsettings.xml and https://forums.scummvm.org/viewtopic.php?t=14379

`-o fluid.reverb.level=.3`

`-o synth.reverb.level=.3`

Both resulted in errors (fluid.reverb.level and synth.reverb.level are valid paramaters.

How can I set the FluidSynth reverb parameters using the command line? 
I am running on Debian (FluidSynth version 1.1.6)

Comment: Off-topic, but in case it helps: I use QSynth as a front-end for FluidSynth. It has a much nicer interface: https://qsynth.sourceforge.io/

Comment: Hi Nikos, I use fluidsynth without a user interface.